# SSH into Debian IOT Device without public ip

Tags: debian, ssh, vpn

I have a BeagleBone like device which runs Debian IOT and connects to the internet using a PPP Connection. The ISP which is used does not provide a public IP.

Now i did try to install a series of Tools to be able to access the device, but nothing works properly.

- Hamachi seems to have problems with the ppp0 Interface (The device is offline as soon as the virtual interface ham0 is up).
- Dataplicity (problems with installing the supervisor)
- Yaler.net (I can access the Welcome Page over the Browser, ssh fails due to Proxy errors (credentials)

Any Idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: To clarify: The BB-like device is installed in a remote location, it is physically connected to something (to what? and how?) which provides internet access using a ppp-connection, and you want to access the device. If it has, say, an ethernet connection, what happens if you take it home and connect it to your Linux PC, and try to simulate the ppp endpoint? (Trace packets with `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, use the equivalent of `pppoe` package for your distro.

Comment: The device is Connected to a Cinterion Modem over ttyO2 and an embedded sim chip. The bblike device does not have a Ethernet connector

Comment: You didn't say which Cinterion Modem or which device ttyO2 corresponds to, but I assume that is a serial connection? So connect it to a serial port of your PC, or use an USB-to-serial adapter. If the ISP does not provide a public IP address, you can't connect to it when it's connected to the ISP, so you *have* to MITM it somehow.

Comment: @dirkt I have access to the device using a USB to Serial adapter and a usb0 ethernet interface - The problem is that i want to have access to the device when it is mounted on a Truck and connected to the internet using the ppp0 interface. I do not have physical access to the device forever

Comment: So (1) choose an internet provider that *does* provide a public address, or (2) install some application on the device which connects to a known public IP address and allows access, e.g. through OpenVPN (then you can ssh in), or through a custom program. It doesn't really matter *how* the device gets internet access (through `ppp0`, or whatever), as long as it has it, any if these methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

Dataplicity here, I think I have spoke with you using our live chat support system and the solution was to manually download supervisor deb files and install them that way. I don't know why Debian IOT had trouble installing supervisor but we'll investigate it and see what can be done about it.